# Notification not received on Xamarin.iOS Google Cloud Messaging (Firebase)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've configured GCM on my Xamarin iOS app using [this](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleiosgcm) component and following the guide shown in the same link.

After adding apns development and distribution apns certificates on my Firebase Cloud Console, my ios application was able to retrieve a registration token correctly so I suppose that it's ready to receive push notifications from server.

In the server side I'm using PushSharp (which support Firebase Cloud Messaging) so, given that the registration (from app) is performed successfully, I'm expecting to receive push notifications too but this not happens :(

Is the xamarin components I'm using that does not support Firebase Cloud Messaging? Or simply I have to send the notification with a different format when sending to an ios device?

Someone has encountered, and maybe resolved this issue?